# Find record by FROM date without TO date on row

Tags: sql, postgresql

consider the following table:

```
foo (
  id: integer,
  from_date: timestamp
  ...
)
```

with values:

```
id | from_date 
--------------
1  | 1990-01-01
2  | 1995-01-01
3  | 2000-01-01
4  | 2005-01-01
5  | 2010-01-01
```

There is no column to_date. Each record with a newer date working as an upper boundary for the previous record. For instance date range for record with id 1 is since `1990-01-01` to `1995-01-01`, if there is no newer record, the range is valid for now.

Can you tell me if there is some handy way how to find a relevant row for a date? For instance:

if I am looking for a valid record for date `2001-01-01`, I expected row with id 3,
if for date `2010-01-01`, I expected row with id 5.

I have no idea how to handle this table design, and I am considering to refactor it and add `to_date` column. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date <= ?
order by t.date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  You haven't specified the database that you are using.  Not all support the standard `fetch` syntax, but all have something equivalent.

An alternative is to use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where ? >= date and
      ? < next_date
```

Comment: thank you for effort, I added db type into tags. I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @DenisStephanov . . .These both work in Postgres.